# Delete File Paths Using Pattern

Tags: matlab

I have a 3x1 string array like this:

```
str = 3x1 string array
"C:\Temp\MyReport.docx"
"C:\Data\Experiment1\Trial1\Sample1.csv"
"C:\Temp\Slides.pptx"
```

I am trying to delete the file extensions such that the only thing remaining is the path:

```
str = 3x1 string
"C:\Temp\MyReport\"
"C:\Data\Experiment1\Trial1\"
"C:\Temp\Slides.pptx\"
```

I tried using this code:

```
match = "/" + wildcardPattern
new_str = erase(str, match);
```

and erase to remove only the extension, but I get an error "unrecognized function 'wilcardpattern'"

Is there a better way to do this, or fix the error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you defining `wildcardpattern` before calling it? The error makes it seem like you don't have a variable for wildcardpattern yet

Answer (score 1):

The `fileparts` ([ref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html)) and `fullfile` ([ref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html)) functions are meant for this kind of work.

If this is your starting point:

```
s = [ ...
    "C:\Temp\MyReport.docx"
    "C:\Data\Experiment1\Trial1\Sample1.csv"
    "C:\Temp\Slides.pptx"
];
```

Then you can compute your desired output, per entry, like this:

```
ix = 1;
[strPath, strName, strExt] = fileparts(  s(ix)  );
x = fullfile( strPath, strName)
```

Now `x = "C:\Temp\MyReport"`.